# Can the automatic db schema update process inside camunda spring boot starter still be used if updating a schema with liquibase is required?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-schema, camunda

We have a spring web app which uses camunda spring boot starter (version 7.18).
We want to leverage the automatic db schema updates from camunda and have our own schema updates via liquibase.

Judging from the official documentation camunda is using liquibase internally as well. So we are unsure on how to achieve the goal of having automatic schema updates from camunda (say when we upgrage 7.18 -> 7.19) and at the same time cover any of the schema updates we would like to track in liquibase as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camunda does not perform automatic schema upgrades when you switch versions. (Only automatic schema creation, which is supposed to be disabled when working with Liquibase according to docs). For schema upgrades you chose either the

- manual path (follow patch level documentation and apply patch manually if one exists; see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#manual-update and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#manual-patch-level-update)
- or you choose to handle updates via Liquibase (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#liquibase-update and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#liquibase-patch-level-update).

(It looks like there have been no recent schema upgrades between patch levels for 2 years: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#patch-level-update)

Comment: Its worth mentioning that running camunda in a spring boot application needs additional setup when using liquibase for migrations and or schema migration. Once camunda encounters a missing schema it terminates before liquibase can finish any schema migration tasks itself. We could not fix that and opted on letting camunda do any initial schema migration and optionally applying any DB update das camunda created schema might need.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? If we upgrade from a version 7.18 to version 7.20 we need to run the databases patchs manually?